# Constantly saving text from UITextview

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextview

In my iOS app I am trying to save the text of a UITextview to a file in the documents directory automatically as the UITextView is being edited. I have an NSTimer that calls the following void function repeatedly:

```
-(void)savetofile{
NSLog(@"Saving");
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *fileName = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@/%@.txt", documentsDirectory,myfilename];
    NSString *content = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:myText.text];
    [content writeToFile:fileName atomically:NO NSDocumentDirectoryingEncoding error:nil];        
}
```

When I run the app, I look at the debug console and it Says "Saving" once then then I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS. What is going on?

Comment: Try to put an exception breakpoint to see where is it failing exactly.

Comment: EXC_BAD_ACCESS happens when you release and deallocated object. Just put break points and find...

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I don't think you should be using a NSTimer, why don't you use the textview delegate to be notified on changes on your UITextView?

secondly, assuming "myText" is you UITextView, I would like you
1) to check if it really is a UITextView at this point of the code
2) to replace your

```
NSString *content = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:myText.text];
```

by a

```
NSString *content = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:myText.text];
```

Well, I don't really see what you need to create a new string for

Comment: I think you meant NSString *content = myText.text; in the second line of code

Comment: in the second line of code I corrected the fact that to make a copy he should have use initWithString and not initWithFormat, if you had read my line written below the second line of code you had know I also agree that creating a new string wasn't necessary and he could have just used myText.text directly

Comment: my bad, I read quickly and thought that the two lines of code were equal, not seeing the change of initWithFormat by initWithString...
The indentation of your answer is kind of confusing

Comment: sorry for the indentation